# All that glitters is gold. No gold is silver.

Tags: predicate-logic, first-order-logic

All that glitters is gold. No gold is silver.

Regarding the above statement, which claims are true?

CLAIMS :

- No silver glitters.
- Some gold glitters.

---

I drew Venn diagram for the following and got both the claims true.

But I don't have the answer for this. Am I right here or missing something ?

Comment: $$\begin{array}{l}\text{All that is gold does not glitter,}\cr
 \text{Not all those who wander are lost;}\cr
 \text{The old that is strong does not wither,}\cr
 \text{Deep roots are not reached by the frost.}\cr
 \text{       }\cr
 \text{From the ashes a fire shall be woken,}\cr
 \text{A light from the shadows shall spring;}\cr
 \text{Renewed shall be blade that was broken,}\cr
 \text{The crownless again shall be king.}\end{array}$$

Comment: @WillJagy, Is that a poetry :P

Answer (score 6):

1. No silver glitters is true, for if silver were to glitter it would be gold, but we are told it is not. So, silver does not glitter.
2. We can't tell whether some gold glitters is true or not on the basis of the premises. For all we know, there is nothing that glitters! The second claim can be true or false. Not enough information has been provided.

Comment: Why 2nd claim is not true ? Venn diagram says it is

Comment: The venn diagram has an open spot in the intersection between glitters and gold, but that does not mean that there is something in that spot. A blank area in the diagram means that we don't know whether there is something there or not. And if there is nothing there (that is, if there is nothing that glitters), then the claim that there is some gold that glitters is false. I am not saying that the claim is false; I am saying that we cannot know the truth value of the second statement on the basis of the premises. Not enough information is provided.

Comment: yes, now that makes sense that where I am wrong. You are implying that it can be a empty set which is trivially subset of gold set, right ?

Comment: Can you say any changes to be made, so that it becomes true ?

Comment: @Garrick if we were told that there is something that glitters, then the claim becomes true, because the Venn diagram shows that the only kind of thing that can glitter is gold.

Comment: See what I understood so far that it is saying "Some gold glitters", means there is definitely some gold that is glittering, but it can be a empty set and empty set is always proper subset of a set(here that is gold), so this claim could be false though not sure because lack of information. But if it is said that "Some gold may glitter", then some gold may glitter or not because there may be some gold or it can be empty set too. Then it is definitely true . Check me now ?

Comment: @Garrick yes, the claim 'some gold may glitter' is true. It is still a possibility that there is gold that glitters.

Comment: Thanks !! For clearing the doubt and such a good discussion.

Comment: @Garrick you're welcome! Did you see my answer to your question from 2 days ago about the managers, executives and leaders?